# Input field validation constraints using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, validation, symfony, annotations

I am working on a symfony(2.8) project. Where in the registration form needs some input validation.
I need to set following constraints on the Subdomain name input field:
1. Should contain only alphanumeric characters
2. First character can not be a number
3. No white spaces

I am using annotations for this task.
Here is the Assert statement I am using:

`@Assert\Regex(pattern="/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]\s+$/", message="Subdomain name must start with a letter and can only have alphanumeric characters with no spaces", groups={"registration"})`

When I enter any simple string of words eg. svits, it still shows the error message "Subdomain name must start with a letter and can only have alphanumeric characters with no spaces"
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `pattern="/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"`. `\s+` matches 1+ whitespaces, why add what you want to forbid?

Comment: I am new to this but anywaysThank you wiktor :)

Comment: Do you want to accept 1 letter words?

Comment: Now I am thinking about it o_O

Comment: :) Use `*` at the end to allow 0 or more characters (and 1 letter words), or Toto's `+` to only allow 2 or more letter words.

Comment: what if I want white spaces? what changes do i make?

Comment: What do you mean? *3. No white spaces*. What are your exact requirements? `pattern="/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/"` would allow whitespaces. And strings like "a         ".

Comment: I have another field by name University name, I need similar constraints on that too, but it should allow white spaces

Comment: Ok, that is another question.

Comment: Yea sorry about that. But `pattern="/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/"` works fine. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @lost I am doing the validation in the entity itself. Like u suggested m not doing it in controller. For unique subdomain I am using `@UniqueEntity(fields="tSubdomainName",message="Subdomain name must be unique",groups={"registration"})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close with your regex, just add quantifier and remove `\s`:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern does not work because:

- The `[a-zA-Z0-9]` only matches 1 alphanumeric character. To match 0 or more, add `*` quantifier (*zero or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern), or `+` (as in Toto's answer) to match *one or more occurrences* (to only match 2+-letter words).
- Since your third requirement forbids the usage of whitespaces in the input string, remove `\s+` from your pattern as it requires 1 or more whitespace symbols at the end of the string.

So, my suggestion is

```
pattern="/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"
                              ^
```

to match 1+ letter words as full strings that start with a letter and may be followed with 0+ any alphanumeric symbols.

To allow whitespaces in any place of the string but the start, put the `\s` into the second `[...]` (character class):

```
pattern="/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/"
                             ^^ ^
```

If you do not want to allow more than 1 whitespace on end (no 2+ consecutive whitespaces), use

```
pattern="/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/"
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` will match 0+ sequences of a single whitespace followed with 1+ alphanumerics.